# Cloud Computing Middleware to Control for Add/Kill VMs + Sessions

Tags: unity, scalability, virtual-machines, cloud-computing

I'm working with some people who have a prototype game in Unity and may need to scale it up to address a larger user base.  The potential application has the following characteristics:

1. Sessions are multiplayer (e.g., multiple users in a game world)
2. Sessions are independent (e.g., each session knows everything it needs to know)
3. Sessions will log some stats to a centralized server (sessions write here, but do not read from there)
4. Session use is likely to be highly uneven (high peak loads of #users and users/session, with long periods of low usage)
5. Users will interact with the system using a browser

Based on these characteristics, a cloud-based service like EC2 seems like an obvious choice.  You only pay for what you use, so you can store an instance of a game server and spin up copies of it when needed, then cut them off when usage bottoms out.  However, doing this requires a server dedicated to managing the # of instances online and helping users get properly allocated to a running server.  From the end-user, I would imagine a system where a user logs into a web portal and requests a list of sessions that they can join.  In the background, the manager would spin up a new session if the number of users waiting in the lobby exceeds the slots available.

In principle, this is a simple concept: you have a lobby, you have a count of users waiting, and you have a count of your servers (and #sessions/server and #users/session).  If your ratio of #waiting/#slots available gets too high, you spin up another VM.  If the ratio gets low, you start shutting some VM's down.  However, in practice this is not likely to be as trivial (lag times to spin up servers are non-trivial, connecting users in browser-based apps to a dynamically-allocated server could have failures, etc).  However, this seems like a fairly general use-case.  Has anyone already made such a lobby controller?  Or even a general load-balancing controller that has similar characteristics?  (Preferably one that would work with EC2)

Or, short question: Does anyone know of a library or server application that would be suitable to balance creating servers and sessions on servers, to dynamically spin up servers for Unity games (on EC2)?  Alternatively, for those who have attempted to home-brew such a system, what were the primary hurdles? (Beyond the obvious fact that it is almost impossible to simulate load meaningfully)

Comment: The best resource I've seen is this on the topic: http://gamasutra.com/blogs/AshkanSaeediMazdeh/20130524/192975/Choosing_the_best_networking_middleware_for_your_Unity_based_multiplayer_or_MMO_game.php

However, it doesn't give a ton of insight into the actual features of specific approaches.  Ideally, I'd be looking for something that is generic (not Unity-specific) since the Unity instances are just one thing that will be running on each VM (and the Unity sessions are all independent anyway).

Comment: Questions that are about "which tech to use" are outside the scope of the site. For more information, see [this meta post](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/).

Comment: I read through that post.  It seems to apply to things that constitute "opinion polls."  This is not an "opinion poll."  This is questioning the existence of such libraries and their maturity for a fairly well-specified application.  If you honestly think that this doesn't belong here, I can withdraw the question.  However, I would think that the answers to this question would be fairly constructive to people looking to scale up an existing application.

Comment: Or, alternatively, which of these do you feel that my question is violating? 1. "They're too localized" (Is load-balancing sessions across cloud computing that localized of an issue?) 2. 
"They may be biased, depending on who gets its hands first on it." (Is there a religious war about cloud-compute middleware for games?  If so, could you just post me a few links and let me go review it?) 3.  "Additionally, the questions are ambiguous and vague." (This is definitely not vague nor ambiguous, IMO.  If you feel it is, I'll add more detail.)

Comment: Altered question title to better reflect general utility of what I am asking for.  I'm happy to revise the question to fit guidelines better, if you can specify them a bit more explicitly.

Comment: It's a poll for technology. At least, indirectly. Most of the questions you're asking are yes|no questions, and it seems as though you're expecting people to volunteer more information beyond that. "*Does anyone know of a library or server application...*" for example. Ideally for you, it would generate a list of responses that you could browse and make your decision. This site isn't really about generating lists. Beyond that, I don't see how this is specific to game development. Server management tech like this could be used in a number of tech fields.

Comment: A few responses.  It's not particularly a poll, but a request to know if someone knows a tool that matches the specification of the task described.  Also, having been around Stackoverflow for a few years now, I'd say the site is exactly about generating lists (unless a list of various answers from different people is somehow not a list).  Secondly, while server management applies to many fields, games and game engines introduce additional restrictions to the space of useful solutions.  While ServerFault may also be a good place to ask, it would be less likely to consider such factors.

Comment: Also, CS/Software Dev is full of issues in the form: "Problem Specification" -> "Solution Paradigms" -> "Specific Implementations."  I stated a particular class of game conditions that would be applicable to a fairly wide range of games.  Lobby applications have been ubiquitous for a decade, even, but I am unaware of their intersection with cloud computing.  Finally, as I have stated, I am happy to rephrase my question.  However, you have not yet explained any conditions that would better specify this question to your taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general problem you are describing (Cloud deployment, auto scale-in/scale-out based on certain metrics) is usually handled by a PaaS - Platform as a Service.

In general, a PaaS allows you to upload your 'application', which could be a VM image or executable files, depending on the PaaS. It is the responsibility of the PaaS to deploy the application to a cloud instance, monitor the application and scale in/out as required.

I don't know of any PaaS that has explicit support for Unity, but the principles hold regardless of what your code does.
There is a comparison of PaaS options here: [PaaS Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542784/looking-for-paas-providers-recommendations)

Disclaimer: I work for [GigaSpaces](http://www.gigaspaces.com), developer of the [Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org) open source PaaS stack.

Comment: Thanks for at least the pointer in the right direction.  I will admit I was hoping for some additional insight about how it intersected with games, but maybe this just isn't the forum for it.